# mongo import create automatically generated created time field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I want to create current time as default value in a `mongodb` document if we didn't provide the value in insert statement.

In mysql there is a provison for that by using the following statement. If we didn't insert the value, a default time value will assign to the row.

```
create table test(name varchar(100), age varchar(10),created_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Is there any approach similar to this in mongodb? I am importing data to mongodb using `mongoimport` from a CSV file. So for every CSV row i want one extra field called "createdAt" which contains the value of import time of the document.

```
mongoimport -d aptigo -c employee --type csv --file /home/weavers/files/csv/Employees.csv --headerline
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision in Mongo to insert default timestamp, instead of that you can get inserted timestamp from the _id value.

`ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mongoose,in that while creating schema you can define default date as,

```
new Schema({ createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now } })
```